# Search usages of Subclass's method

Tags: intellij-idea

I have parent class Parent with method `getToken()`. And I have its child class - `ChildA` and `ChildB`, which don't override method `getToken()`.

How I can search usages of method `getToken()` which used by instance of class `ChildA`?

Sorry for my English. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add `getToken()` to `ChildA`, perform the search only for this method, then delete it. Another way is to use [Structural Search and Replace](http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Basics_of_working_with_structural_search).

Answer (score 12):

As I spent half an hour to find the exact solution through all complicated and outdated documentations and examples, I just put the full answer using SSR here (Intellij 15.0.5):

Open SSR dialog (Edit > Find > Search Structurally...) and input template in screenshot, then click on "Edit variables..." to see the second dialog and edit the "Expression type (regexp)" as shown:

[image]

and if you want to include subclasses of ChildA too, just check the box "Apply constraint within type hierarchy" bellow the expression type:

[image]

Comment: Can't believe this only has one upvote. Really useful example. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Intellij asks about this if you use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> for the search. First you have to explicitly override the method in the subclass/subinterface though, as CrazyCoder suggested.